# How to include specific folder in the Maven generated jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, pom.xml

I have the following Maven project structure:

```
${basedir}/ 
  - pom.xml
  - lib/
    - dependency1.jar
    - dependency2.jar
    - ...
  - src/
    - main/..
    - test/..
  - target/
    - classes/..
    - blah/
    - uggh/
```

How can I modify the pom file in order to include the entire lib folder (with its content) in the generated output jar?

This folder includes third parties jars that can not be part of the Maven repository.

Comment: Really having a lib folder which contains jar files? If yes you are doing Maven wrong...should be defined as dependencies but not being part of the project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `maven-jar-plugin` to copy the dependencies from lib into your fat jar

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. In case I want to specify also the exact target location? 
for instance: <myproject.jar>/lib/....jars

Answer (score 0):

for specifying the exact jar location include the following in your `<plugin>` under `<build>`:

```
<configuration>             
  <outputDirectory>
    ${project.basedir}/../build/jars
  </outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```